# expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #4 'mat1'

Tags: backend, pytorch

I am trying to re_train FC layer of resnet50 on my dataset. After loading the data set and pre-train model, I move both to the device but I am getting

> > error:
> >     Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #4 'mat1'

I searched a lot online found that mainly this kind of error occurs due to if the model is not moved or input to the model is not moved to GPU. I did both but still, no luck. Here are code and error.

```
    if steps % print_every == 0:
        test_loss = 0
        accuracy = 0
        resnet50.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, labels in testloader:
                inputs, labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)
                logps = resnet50.forward(inputs)
                batch_loss = criterion(logps, labels)
                test_loss += batch_loss.item()

                ps = torch.exp(logps)
                top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
                equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)

               accuracy+=torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()
        train_losses.append(running_loss/len(trainloader))
        test_losses.append(test_loss/len(testloader))                    
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{Epochs}.. "
              f"Train loss: {running_loss/print_every:.3f}.. "
              f"Test loss: {test_loss/len(testloader):.3f}.. "
              f"Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(testloader):.3f}")
        running_loss = 0
        resnet50.train()
```

Comment: move your model to gpu? `resnet50=resnet50.to(device=device)`

Comment: that was also  already moved @UmangGupta